# python, matrix transpose with odd row reversed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, reverse

How can I print this result using numpy **without** using functions as `reshape` or `.T`or `reverse` and purely through using a **for loop or list comprehension**?

Below is an example of what I am trying to ask:
How can I convert this:

```
[[ 1.  5.  9.]
 [ 2.  6.  10.]
 [ 3.  7.  11.]
 [ 4.  8.  12.]]
```

to this:

```
[[ 1.  8.  9.]
 [ 2.  7.  10.]
 [ 3.  6.  11.]
 [ 4.  5.  12.]]
```

This is code I have written so far:

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.ones((4,3))
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(3):
        arr[i,j]+=i
        arr[i,j]+=j*5
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using no `numpy` functions to reverse odd columns you could do something like:

```py
import numpy as np

# just your input data
mat = np.arange(1.0, 13.0).reshape(3, 4).T

mat_no_numpy = np.zeros_like(mat)
rows, cols = mat.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if j % 2 == 0:
            mat_no_numpy[i, j] = mat[i, j]
        else:
            # flip row-coordinate for odd columns
            mat_no_numpy[i, j] = mat[rows - i - 1, j]

print(mat_no_numpy)
# [[ 1.  8.  9.]
#  [ 2.  7. 10.]
#  [ 3.  6. 11.]
#  [ 4.  5. 12.]]
```

---

Alternatively, if `numpy` functions are allowed, you can use a combination of slicing and [`np.flip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) to flip every odd column:

```py
import numpy as np

# just your input data
mat = np.arange(1.0, 13.0).reshape(3, 4).T

mat[:, 1::2] = np.flip(mat[:, 1::2])
print(mat)
# [[ 1.  8.  9.]
#  [ 2.  7. 10.]
#  [ 3.  6. 11.]
#  [ 4.  5. 12.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!
'''
import numpy as np


arr= np.ones((5,4))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(4):
        arr[i,j]+=i
        arr[i,j]+=j*5
        
        if j % 2 == 0:
            arr[i, j]
        else:
            arr[i, j] = arr[4-i, j]
print(arr)
'''
I'm going to take the code you made and apply it to my code(code I have written so far), but this part is stucked, so I can't solve it! mat[rows-i-1, j]

Comment: [[ 1.  1. 11.  1.]
 [ 2.  1. 12.  1.]
 [ 3.  8. 13. 18.]
 [ 4.  1. 14.  1.]
 [ 5.  1. 15.  1.]]

this is what i printed out. 
It seems i don't understand it well '''[rows-i-1, j] '''

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. `[rows - i - 1, j]` takes the `j`-th column and in it not the `i`-th element, but "the opposite". Given an array with `5` rows, we first subtract `1` since `4` is the highest possible index. And instead of the `0`-th element, we then take the `4 - 0`-th element, thus mirroring ("flipping") the column.